# How can I make React popup notification kind of code

Tags: reactjs, notifications

`position` takes the value for `transform: translateY()`.

Problem is that I can not return the `position` value back to `-100%`. How can I return value back after 3 seconds?

It is my first question so please sorry if asked not properly.

```
let position = "-100%";

  if (message !== "") {
    position = "0";
    setTimeout(() => {
      position = "-100%";
      clearMessage();
    }, 3000);
  }

  return <StyledNotification show={position}>{message}</StyledNotification>;
```

Comment: you have to use `state` instead using a variable

Comment: It shows me: Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've tried to implement it via state but it was returning me an error: **Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.** Then I decided to add lifecycle method to track on what change it needs to run the code to avoid looping. In my case *change* was *message*. Nevertheless, thanks to everyone for feedback!

```
    const [position, setPosition] = useState("-100%");
    useEffect(() => {
      if (message !== "") {
        setPosition("0");
        setTimeout(() => {
          setPosition("-100%");
        }, 3000);
      }
    }, [message]);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the state to set the position value

```
const [position, setPosition] = useState('')

  if (message !== "") {
    setPosition("0%");
    setTimeout(() => {
       setPosition("-100%");
      clearMessage();
    }, 3000);
  }
```

check this sandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-proskuriakova-pnqcg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Yeah, I've tried this case already but it shows the next: Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: check this out on sandbox, It is working for me.
 https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-proskuriakova-pnqcg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark